# Paint a shape on mouse click with Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, actionlistener, paintcomponent

I am trying to create a java program that will paint a shape on a JFrame when the user clicks on the Frame.  I have gotten to the point where I have it set up to accept different shapes and recognize the clicks, but I am having trouble figuring out how to implement the painting of the shape.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class StamperFrame extends JFrame {

    private JButton circleButton, ovalButton, squareButton, rectButton;
    private int buttonValue = 0;

    public StamperFrame() {
        setTitle("Shape Stamper");
        setSize(500, 500);

        //Setting up the buttons and positioning them.
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        circleButton = new JButton("Circle");
        ovalButton = new JButton("Oval");
        squareButton = new JButton("Square");
        rectButton = new JButton("Rectangle");

        buttonPanel.add(circleButton);
        buttonPanel.add(ovalButton);
        buttonPanel.add(squareButton);
        buttonPanel.add(rectButton);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //end button init



        //Setting up button logic
        circleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonValue = 1;
                System.out.println(buttonValue);
            }
        });
        ovalButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonValue = 2;
                System.out.println(buttonValue);
            }
        });
        squareButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonValue = 3;
                System.out.println(buttonValue);
            }
        });
        rectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonValue = 4;
                System.out.println(buttonValue);
            }
        });
        //end button click configuration

        getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (buttonValue == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Circle added at: " + e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
                } else if (buttonValue == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Oval added at: " + e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
                }else if (buttonValue == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Square added at: " + e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
                }else if (buttonValue == 4) {
                    System.out.println("Rectangle added at: " + e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I know it needs to work into my mouse event some how, but I can't figure out how.

My Frame currently looks like this: http://puu.sh/8ELaR/c7252286c0.jpg

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two ways to do custom painting:

1. Add Objects to paint to an ArrayList
2. Paint the Object directly onto a BufferedImage.

The examples in the link only draw a Rectanle so you will obviously need to modify the code to support different Shapes, but it should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Real complete aswer now:

**TL;DR**: Copy and Paste the following code:

```
package FinalExam;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StamperFrame extends JFrame {

    private final JButton circleButton, ovalButton, squareButton, rectButton;

    private final JPanel shapesPanel;

    private Shape shape;
    private final int w = 100;
    private final int h = 200;

    private Object lastButtonPressed;

    public StamperFrame() {
        setTitle("Shape Stamper");
        setSize(500, 500);

        final Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        //Setting up the buttons and positioning them.
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        circleButton = new JButton("Circle");
        ovalButton = new JButton("Oval");
        squareButton = new JButton("Square");
        rectButton = new JButton("Rectangle");

        buttonPanel.add(circleButton);
        buttonPanel.add(ovalButton);
        buttonPanel.add(squareButton);
        buttonPanel.add(rectButton);

        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //end button init

        shapesPanel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
                super.paintComponent(g); 
                if(shape != null) g.draw(shape);
            }

        };
        contentPane.add(shapesPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final ActionListener buttonPressed = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                lastButtonPressed = event.getSource();
            }
        };

        circleButton.addActionListener(buttonPressed);
        ovalButton.addActionListener(buttonPressed);
        squareButton.addActionListener(buttonPressed);
        rectButton.addActionListener(buttonPressed);

        contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();

                if(lastButtonPressed == circleButton){
                    shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, w);
                    echo("Circle",x,y);
                } else if(lastButtonPressed == ovalButton){
                    shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
                    echo("Oval",x,y);
                } else if (lastButtonPressed == squareButton){
                    shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, w);
                    echo("Square",x,y);
                } else if (lastButtonPressed == rectButton){
                    echo("Rectangle",x,y);
                    shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
                } 

                shapesPanel.repaint();
            }

            private void echo(String shape, int x, int y){
                System.out.println(shape + " added at: " + x + "," + y);
            }

        });

    }
}
```

**Long explanation**

1. We don't need a variable buttonValue to remember which button was pressed. The button is the event source, so we just store it and we can know later which one was pressed.
2. We don't need 4 instances of `ActionListener` (one for each button), since they all do the same thing (to store the event source as the "button that was pressed'
3. The drawing trick is done by using a `JPanel` (the shapesPanel variable) as a "drawing canvas". We extend JPanel to override the `paintComponent`. This method will use the shape-drawing API of `Graphics2D`.
4. An `ActionListener` added at the `contentPane` will get the x and y coordinates of the click, create the `Shape` to be drawn (based on what was the last `lastButtonPressed`),  store it at variable `shape` and ask the `shapesPanel` to `repaint()` itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback.  I actually made a new question because I got the program to paint on click now, but the repaint() method is causing an issue I need to solve.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557416/java-graphics2d-transparent-backgrounds?noredirect=1#comment36158663_23557416           The issue is with repaint(), but I am not sure on the fix.  I will definitely take your advice and reduce the number of ActionListeners.

Answer (score -1):

You will add a new JPanel to your content pane, probably at the center

```
JPanel drawingPanel = new JPanel();
getContentPane().add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then you will, at each button's action listerner code call the code to draws on the JPanel's graphics:

```
rectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           Graphics2D g = Graphics2D drawingPanel.getGraphics2D(); 
           g.draw(new java.awt.Rectangle(42,42,20,40);

        }
    });
```

and so on...

You will need to get acquainted to Java2D to finish you work on the FinalExam package.

Comment: -1, you should NOT use getGraphics() to do painting. Any painting you do will be temporary and will be lost the first time Swing determines the components needs to be repainted.

Comment: You're right. I guess one should override paintComponent(Graphics g), check that weird buttonValue property and draws the Shape. repaint() should be called somewhere, of course. I hate finalExams.